# How to pick a group of elements in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a big array with **some of the elements are arrays**.

**Some of the elements and sub-elements** are , Let's say, "forbbidden names".

Now, if I input a name that is one of the forbbidden names, I want to make it invalid.

My question is-- how to get an array of "forbbidden names"?

Comment: Are we talking arbitrary depth or just maximum 2? Also, why do they need to be nested and is there any rule by which they are?

Comment: show us that array and I think we could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are a bit unclear, I assume you want to extract the forbidden names and check the input against it.

```
            function getForbiddenNames($array){

                $output = array();
                foreach( $array as $key=>$value) {

                if(is_array($value)) //recursive call
                    array_merge($output , getForbiddenNames($value));

                else if(isForbidden($value)) 
                   array_push($output , $value);

    }

if(in_array($input, getForbiddenNames($corpus))
return 'catch!' ;
```